# Scala Spark : How to create a RDD from a list of string and convert to DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd, union-all

I want to create a DataFrame from a list of string that could match existing schema. 
Here is my code.

```
    val rowValues = List("ann", "f", "90", "world", "23456") // fails
    val rowValueTuple = ("ann", "f", "90", "world", "23456") //works

    val newRow = sqlContext.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(rowValueTuple)).toDF(df.columns: _*)

    val newdf = df.unionAll(newRow).show()
```

The same code fails if i use the List of String. I see the difference is with `rowValueTuple` a `Tuple` is created. 
Since the size of `rowValues` list dynamically changes, i cannot manually create `Tuple*` object.
How can i do this? What am i missing? How can i flatten this list to meet the requirement?

Appreciate your help, Please.

Comment: The first gives you a DF with one column and 5 rows. The second gives you a DF with a single row with a single column that  contains a tuple. Very different things.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

DataFrame has schema with fixed number of columns, so it's seems not natural to make row per list of variable length. Anyway, you can create your DataFrame from RDD[Row] using existing schema, like this:

```
val rdd = sqlContext.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(rowValues))
val rowRdd = rdd.map(v => Row(v: _*))
val newRow = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, df.schema)
```

Comment: Thanks @vitality . I did try this. But missed something. I agree with your point. But i want to perform this for given pair of dataframe and list of row values as parameters. The number of column of dataframe and length of row values is assumed to be same.

Comment: Just a note here, the last line should be

```val newRow = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRdd, df.schema)```
At least that's what worked for me.

Comment: @Rylan: What is `df` here?

Comment: If pyspark instead of scala, then what would be the map line of code?